# selenium-webdriver pass chrome arguments in node

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am using selenium in node:

```
require('chromedriver');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'), By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
```

Is there any way how to pass command line arguments and start chrome hidden using headless mode?

How?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it this way

```
require('chromedriver');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'), By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until,  chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().headless())
  .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
```